# Kotlin passing variable number of arguments to function

Tags: android, kotlin

Google Maps has a function that allows you to pass any number of arguments to it.  But I don't know how many arguments I want to pass in up front :(

Currently my code looks like this.  It has arguments added in, but this is hardcoded.  I want this to be variable.  How can I do this in Kotlin?

```
polyLine= gMap.addPolyline(
            PolylineOptions()
                .add(_moments.get(0).position,
                    _moments.get(1).position,
                    _moments.get(2).position
                )
          )
```

Something like this?

```
polyLine= gMap.addPolyline(
            PolylineOptions()
                .add( for (i in 1..MAX_LIST_COUNT) {_moments.get(i).position} )
          )
```

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Pass an array or list using the spread operator. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`addAll`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions.html#addAll(java.lang.Iterable%3Ccom.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%3E)) instead:

```
PolylineOpions().addAll(_moments.map { it.position })
```

If you are just interested on how to pass something to a vararg method, then have a look at the [spread operator for vararg functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs). An example usage:

```
PolylineOptions().add(*_moments.map { it.position }.toTypedArray())
```